# Exist a endomorphism $f$ on $V$ such that $Im (f) = W$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $V$ is a finite vector space, $W$ is a subspace of $V$. Show that:
>
> 1. Exist a endomorphism $f$ on $V$ such that $Im (f) = W$.
> 2. Exist a endomorphism $g$ on $V$ such that $Ker (g) = W$.

**My attempt:**
Consider a homomorphism $h$ on $V$. Let $f = h|_{W}: W \rightarrow V$, we have $Im(f) = f(W)$. The remainder of this problem is $f(W) = W$ implies $f = id(W)$.

On the one hand, consider $g = h|_{W}: W \rightarrow V$ such that $g(w)=0, \forall w \in W$. Q.E.D

Is my solution right?

Comment: The sentence $f(W)=W$ does not imply that $f$ is the identity on $W$. For instance, the linear transformation $x\rightarrow 2x$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ sends $\mathbb{R}$ to itself but is not the identity. Moreover, you need $f$ to be an endormorphism *on $V$*. However, the $f$ you try to construct is a linear mapping from $W$ to $V$. It does not meet the requirement of the question. As for the second question, how do you precisely justify the existence of an endomorphism that is $0$ on $W$ and **only** on $W$?

Comment: I believe that's exists an endomorphism like the problem remainded, but I can not find it.

Comment: Hint: use the fact that $V$ is finite dimensional. Consider a basis for it that is adapted to $W$. Then, try to build endomorphisms using this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{w_1,\ldots,w_m\}$ be a basis for $W.$ Extend this basis to a basis for $V,$ $\{w_1,\ldots,w_m,v_1,\ldots,v_p\},$ where $m+p = \dim V.$

Define $f : \{w_1,\ldots,w_m,v_1,\ldots,v_p\}\longrightarrow V$ by $f(w_i)=w_i$ for $1\leq i \leq m$ and $0$ otherwise. Then $f$ extends uniquely to a linear map $L_f,$ and $\text{Img}(L_f) = W.$

Define $g : \{w_1,\ldots,w_m,v_1,\ldots,v_p\}\longrightarrow V$ by $g(w_i)=0$ for $1\leq i \leq m$ and $g(v_j)=v_j$ for $1\leq p$ . Then $g$ extends uniquely to a linear map $L_g,$ and $\ker(L_g) = W.$

Comment: Do you mean $g(v_j)=v_j$ for $1\leq j\leq p$?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have corrected it.